# What's the leaf work in streams?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm reading a Java 8 book by Richard Warburton. Here's the quote I didn't quite understand:

> Let's assume that the streams framework is splitting up our work to
>   operate in parallel on a four-core machine:
>
> 1. Our data source is decomposed into four chunks of elements.
> 2. We perform ***leaf computation work*** in parallel on each thread [...]

What is the **leaf computation work**? What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm assuming it is referring to the work of processing the smallest chunks of elements, which get processed by a single thread instead of being broken down to smaller chunks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author uses the tree-leaf analogy to explain subdivision of work in parallel streams.

Think of the entire body of work that needs to be done as a tree. Trunk represents the whole work; each branch represents some portion of the work that can be further subdivided; each leaf represents the amount of work that is not subdivided any further.

Consider merge-sorting an array of 8 elements as an example. Sorting elements 0..7 is the trunk. It has two branches for sorting ranges 0..3 and 4..7. In turn, each branch has two leaves for sorting two-element ranges.

Since the job of sorting two-element range is not subdivided any further, it's considered a *leaf*.

[image: Sort tree]

Comment: Though the sorting example is a bit misleading, as it requires a non-trivial merging step (and therefore, it’s important that the two non-leaf nodes also run in parallel, though they can’t utilize all four cores). Apparently, the original source uses a simpler example of summing.

Comment: @Holger That's true. I picked sorting so that my tree wouldn't look like a bush :-)

Comment: Well, the OP didn’t cite enough, so I searched for the original example and found that it focuses on subdividing to “number of CPU core” leaf nodes, as the Stream implementation does, but coincidentally also had four leaf nodes, each of them summing 1/N elements, then having a trivial merge step. (`listOfInteger .parallelStream() .mapToInt(i -> i) .sum()`)